# What is the purpose of address_get?

Tags: python, odoo-13

Please tell me what is the purpose of `address_get()`? Why we use this?
Here in the sales module `"sale.py"`, it is used as:

```
addr = self.partner_id.address_get(['delivery', 'invoice'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to find needed addresses from three structure.

From Source:

> Find contacts/addresses of the right type(s) by doing a depth-first-search through descendants within company boundaries (stop at entities flagged `is_company`) then continuing the search at the ancestors that are within the same company boundaries. Defaults to partners of type `'default'` when the exact type is not found, or to the provided partner itself if no type `'default'` is found either.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/ce6f6fb4e04746d28e1b959d50f50a855c7a3049/odoo/addons/base/models/res_partner.py#L855